# Problems building nodejs on MacOS Snow Leopard

Tags: mac-osx, node.js

I am having trouble building nodejs on MacOS Snow Leopard.  I think it
might have something to do with my PATH variable not being set
correctly for the developer tools location.

For some reason, the Developer tools (gcc, g++, make etc) are all
stored in

> /Developer/usr/bin

I added it to my PATH variable as follows:

> $ export PATH=$PATH:/Developer/usr/bin

```
$ echo $PATH
/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Developer/usr/bin
```

When i try to configure it complains about not finding open-ssl, ok,
not a big problem.  So I try with --without-ssl :

```
$ ./configure --without-ssl
Checking for program g++ or c++          : /Developer/usr/bin/g++
Checking for program cpp                 : /Developer/usr/bin/cpp
Checking for program ar                  : /usr/bin/ar
Checking for program ranlib              : /Developer/usr/bin/ranlib
Checking for g++                         : ok
Checking for program gcc or cc           : /Developer/usr/bin/gcc
Checking for gcc                         : ok
Checking for library dl                  : yes
Checking for library util                : yes
Checking for library rt                  : not found
--- libeio ---
Checking for library pthread             : yes
Checking for function pthread_create     : not found
/Users/Guy/git_src/node/node/deps/libeio/wscript:13: error: the
configuration failed (see
'/Users/Guy/git_src/node/node/build/config.log')
```

Anyone know how I can get round this?  I am suspicious that it might
be something to do with the PATH or another ENV variable, but not
sure.

Thanks

G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best bet with anything Mac is install homebrew

```
http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/
```

Then you can do

```
brew install node.js
```